# Disable "Slow Charger" warning in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, notification-area

I have several laptops which support USB-C charging, and a 65W GaN PD charger.  It's nice to have a compact power supply that works on a bunch of different laptops, even if it can't deliver the full power provided by their dedicated chargers -- it's plenty for keeping the battery topped up while doing light web browsing and whatnot.

On some of them, every time I plug in, I get a notification saying "Slow Charger", and that I really should use the packed-in charger instead.  I know it's slow, I don't care, but the notification often pops up over something I'm trying to read and doesn't seem to go away on its own.

I don't think I get this warning (or it's not the exact same warning) on every system that supports PD charging.  The one that's bugging me now is on a Surface Book 2, if that makes a difference.  I just want to change a registry setting or something to stop the warning from appearing, but I haven't been able to find anything about it online.  Does anybody know where this warning comes from?  Can I kill it permanently?

Comment: For my own reference as much as anybody else: the accepted solution does not actually work for me.  I've reported it in Feedback Hub (search for "notifications about charging slowly"); in the meantime you can select the notification popup using they keyboard with `Win`+`Shift`+`V`, so you can at least close it without using the mouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the article
[How to Turn On or Off PC Charging Slowly over USB Notification in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111133-turn-off-pc-charging-slowly-over-usb-notification-windows-10-a.html).

The setting is found in the registry at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shell\USB`.
The item name is `NotifyOnWeakCharger`, type DWORD,
and its values are `0` for Off and `1` for On.

The following `.reg` file will set it to disabled:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shell\USB]
"NotifyOnWeakCharger"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: It's worth noting that your link shows that this is exposed in the modern Settings, under "USB", with a simple checkbox.  Thanks!

Comment: Weirdly, this seemed to work the first time I tried it, but I just plugged in my USB charger and it popped up again.  I double checked that the modern-settings page still has the relevant box unchecked, and just to be sure I looked at the reg key you posted.  Both are correct, still got notified.  Guess I need to report it in Feedback Hub or something.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either. If anything, it increases the frequency of "slow charger" warnings...

Comment: Regedit or GUI both dont' work

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has disabled this option? If that's the case, we're all out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue charging my laptop from USB-C Screen.

Setting it in Window's USB settings did the job.
From menu start, search '`USB`', then USB Settings -> Uncheck '`Notify me if my PC is charging slowly over USB`'.

No need to touch registry, can be done withtou admin privileges and can be easily brought back.

[image: USB settings]

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned this in a comment on the other answer but your screenshot might be helpful if anybody has trouble finding it.  I'm glad it worked for you, though as I've commented I still get notified even with the box unchecked.

Comment: Actually, now both solutions simply stopped working for me :D

Comment: I'm on Windows 11. This doesn't work for me either. I used the *.reg file solution from the accepted answer above. Now, when I go to Settings > USB settings, the "Show a notification if this PC is charging slowly over USB" option is switched off, but I still see the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers refer to Windows 10, it is worth adding that in Windows 11 the notification can be disabled in Settings -> Bluetooth & devices -> USB -> Show a notification if this PC is charging slowly over USB.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, these suggestions do not work on my ThinkPad Yoga at all.  I'm starting to wonder if an old battery that doesn't charge as well might cause this?  Otherwise, these suggestions are just BS depending upon the device.  There has to be other dependancies that all these submitters are not aware of.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).